# Ordered random numbers in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, random

I am trying to generate random numbers between 1 and 5 using Matlab's `randperm` and calling `randperm = 5`.

Each time this gives me a different array let's say for example:

```
x = randperm(5)
x = [3 2 4 1 5]
```

I need the vector to be arranged such that 4 and 5 are always next to each other and 2 is always between 1 and 3... so for e.g. `[3 2 1 4 5]` or `[4 5 1 2 3]`.

So essentially I have two "blocks" of unequal length - `1 2 3` and `4 5`. The order of the blocks is not so important, just that 4 & 5 end up together and 2 in between 1 and 3.

I can basically only have 4 possible combinations:

```
[1 2 3 4 5]

[3 2 1 4 5]

[4 5 1 2 3]

[4 5 3 2 1]
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Use `randperm` for both blocks and a `randperm(2)` for how to index them.

Comment: Since you have a very restricted number of possible combinations, create an array out of these then randomly pick a row from it using `randi`.

Comment: Does it always have to be `4 5`? None of your possible combinations show `5 4`.

Comment: @Adriaan: I count 8 possibilities: the four above, plus another four with the 4 and 5 swapped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate each block and shuffle each one then and set them as members of a cell array and shuffle the cell array and finally convert the cell array to a vector.

```
b45=[4 5];                                        % block 1
b13=[1 3];                                        % block 2
r45 = randperm(2);                                % indices for shuffling block 1
r13 = randperm(2);                                % indices for shuffling block 2
r15 = randperm(2);                                % indices for shuffling the cell
blocks = {b45(r45) [b13(r13(1)) 2 b13(r13(2))]};  % shuffle each block and set them a members of a cell array
result = [blocks{r15}]                            % shuffle the cell and convert to a vector
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you want a solution that would somehow generalize to a larger problem, but based on how you've described your problem above it looks like you are only going to have 8 possible combinations that satisfy your constraints:

```
possible = [1 2 3 4 5; ...
            1 2 3 5 4; ...
            3 2 1 4 5; ...
            3 2 1 5 4; ...
            4 5 1 2 3; ...
            5 4 1 2 3; ...
            4 5 3 2 1; ...
            5 4 3 2 1];
```

You can now randomly select one or more of these rows using [`randi`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html), and can even create an [anonymous function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to do it for you:

```
randPattern = @(n) possible(randi(size(possible, 1), [1 n]), :)
```

This allows you to select, for example, 5 patterns at random (one per row):

```
>> patternMat = randPattern(5)

patternMat =

     4     5     3     2     1
     3     2     1     4     5
     4     5     3     2     1
     1     2     3     5     4
     5     4     3     2     1
```